# Bootstrap Nav Only on Mobile and On Desktop w/ Scroll

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get a Bootstrap 4 top-sticky nav to only appear on mobile, which would alone be easy with CSS (*d-block d-md-none*), but on desktop I instead want it to fade-in when the user scrolls down past a certain point, and hides when you scroll back up. This is what I have figured out, but it causes the menu to show briefly on load on desktop.

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar").hide();
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if($(window).width() >= 768) { 
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
                    $('.navbar').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $('.navbar').fadeOut();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
  }(jQuery));
```

It could also work with adding and removing classes, which would prevent the flicker, although that makes for an abrupt transition and I'm having trouble getting it to work in the first place:

```
$(function() {
    var div = $(".navbar");
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 200) {
            div.removeClass('d-block').removeClass("d-md-none");
        } else {
            div.addClass("d-block").addClass('d-md-none');
        }
    });
});
```

I would appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the flashing navbar on load. What's happening is the .hide() occurs when the document is finished loading. We could assign it via css so that the navbar would appear hidden initially.

It could be fixed by adding `display:none` to the navbar and by removing the `$(".navbar").hide();`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="display:none;">
...
</nav>
```

```
<script>
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // remove
    // $(".navbar").hide();
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if($(window).width() >= 768) { 
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
                    $('.navbar').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $('.navbar').fadeOut();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
  }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Here's a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oe5s6z0c/1/
In this fiddle I added

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="position:fixed; display:none; width:100%;">
...
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to use a combination of JS and CSS media queries to accomplish what I wanted. The media queries ensure that JS utilizes only apply on desktop browsers, while adding a nice easing when the JS adds and removes classes.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
      opacity: 1!important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  }
}

(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // scroll functions
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        if($(window).width() >= 768) 

            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= 150) {
                $('.navbar').addClass("navbar-hide");
            } else {
                $('.navbar').removeClass("navbar-hide");
        }

    });

    });

})(jQuery);
```